# Bit-bang TX problem

Tags: bit-bang

I need some help. I had to create a new serial for my motherboard. I decided to emulate a serial via bit bang. The code is below. I am finding problem in my code sync bit bang with a traditional RS232 code. The mainboard is generating the signal correctly, but the receiver can not identify the number sent correctly.

```c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "bit_bang.h"
#include <util\delay.h>
#define tx_pin_high() PORTB |= (1<<7)
#define tx_pin_low() PORTB &= ~(1<<7)



void init_port_bit_bag()
{

    DDRB = 0xFF; 
    PORTB  = 0x00; 
}

void uart_tx_bit_bang_8bit(unsigned char data)
{

    unsigned int i = 0;
    tx_pin_low();

    _delay_us(2);

    for( i=8 ; i!=0 ; --i) //LSB BIT
    {
        if(data & 0x01) 
        {
            tx_pin_high(); 
        }
        else 
        {
            tx_pin_low(); 
        }

        data >>= 1;
        _delay_us(156);
    }

    tx_pin_high();
    _delay_us(2);
}
```

I have tested this code and it is working perfectly. The loop to generate the word is spending 625.25us sent per byte, thus achieving almost ideal to have the 9600 bps. What I need is to synchronize this code with a **serial RS 232 traditional or create a serial bit bang receiving**. I performed some tests using traditional functions of RS 232 and folow the code below, the received is different from what is being sent. Can anyone help me please? The serial data receiver is picking up different than what I'm sending.

```c
char uart_getchar (void)
{
    while (!(UCSRA & (1 << RXC)));
    return UDR;
}

while (1)
{          
           rx = uart_getchar();
           _delay_ms(30);

            uart_string("Information:");
        uart_putchar('\n');
        uart_putchar((rx/10)%10+'0');
        uart_putchar(rx%10+'0');
        uart_putchar('\n');
        _delay_ms(1000);
}
```

That's what I'm sent.

```c
#include <avr\io.h>
#include <avr\interrupt.h>
#include <util\delay.h>
#include "bit_bang.h"

int main(void)
{   
    char date1 = 6;   

    init_port_bit_bag();
    while (1)
    {
    uart_tx_bit_bang_8bit(date1);
    _delay_ms(10);
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the numbers 7, 14, 15,17. I think the error is in the synchronization of start bit.

Comment: It might help if you gave an example of what data was sent and what was received (in error). Is it consistently wrong i.e. for X sent, Y is always received or is Y a bit random. This is important to say.

Comment: I edited the post and put what I sent and received. Basically I'm sending the number 6 and the number receiving 7,14,15. Depends on when I get different information

Comment: Where are your start and stop bits?

Comment: Is the first code. When I use tx_pin_low and tx_pin_high. This is the code for the bit bang. On another board I'm using a traditional RS232.

Comment: Why would you delay for 2us when all the other bits are 156us?

Comment: I put that time to be the time of the star and stop bit. And the 156 us is to make the length of one byte closest to the 625us (1/16M) to achieve a rate of 9600bps.It is necessary I put the same delay?

Comment: I switched to the same delay and signal oscilloscope was much better than it was before. But the error still confrence. I sent the number 6 and RS232 receives 28 now.

Comment: Where did 625uS come from ? That's only 6 bit's worth of time.. you need 104us x 8 + start bit + stop bit for 1 byte = approx 1ms. See @markrages answer for details

Answer (score 2):

If you want to transmit at 9600 baud, your delays are wrong.
$$\frac{1}{9600} \approx 104 {\mu}s$$
You need 104 microseconds for each bit period.  Start and stop bits are also 104 microseconds. Now, you will probably have to subtract processing time from the delay.  You can find this by studying the processor's instruction timing and writing in assembly, or cheat and just measure on an oscilloscope.

But for sure `_delay_us(2);` and `_delay_us(156);` are wrong.

Comment: Or cheat harder and use a timer interrupt.

Comment: The hardest cheat would be to use the UART hardware.